# Anonymous function in place of function ref in python

Tags: python

in `threading.timer` you pass the name of a function (example below). Is it possible to replace this with the function body so I dont have to bother defining another trivial function

```
def PulseLed(self):
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
    self.ledTimer = threading.Timer(1, self.TurnOffLed)
    self.ledTimer.start()

def TurnOffLed(self):
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: You _are not_ passing name in this example, you are passing a method object. Why not try to simply replace it with anonymous function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's syntax does not allow including **statements** in argument lists.  Often you can use a `lambda`, though, like:

```
threading.Timer(1, lambda: GPID.output(26, GPIO.LOW))
```

Overused, this can lead to unreadable code.  You know it's "overused" if you start to stuff multiple `x if b else y` clauses into your lambda ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
self.ledTimer = threading.Timer(1, lambda: GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm always partial to `partial`:

```
from functools import partial

def PulseLed(self):
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
    self.ledTimer = threading.Timer(1, partial(GPIO.output, 26, GPIO.LOW))
    self.ledTimer.start()
```

Comment: I think using `functools.partial` is an overkill (simple lambda would do), but it still works. Upvoting.

Comment: When all you want to do is bind some static positional arguments, it's hard to see how `partial` is overkill, or underkill. When you start doing convoluted things with it, or trying to combine it with a `compose` function, that's when you realize you're not actually writing Python anymore… (Well, that's when _I_ realize; maybe some people realize it faster.)

Answer (score 2):

I like the "trivial function" in many cases; however, I would write it similar to following. I find that using *local* functions - just as with using local variables - can add "self documentation" to code.

```
def PulseLed(self):
    def tunOffLed():
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
    self.ledTimer = threading.Timer(1, turnOffLed)
    self.ledTimer.start()
```

(Perhaps even put the other GPIO call in a `turnOnLed` function.)

Comment: If we had [PEP 403](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0403/) you could even make it statement-local instead of function-local. Which really isn't any more readable in this case, or in most cases, which is why Nick Coghlan deferred the PEP, but some day someone will find a killer use case for it…

Comment: @abarnert I can't say I like the syntax proposed, but it's a nice read (thanks for the link!). Some languages allow similar constructs already, showing that there is merit with some code/cases (question is then if it fits the Python Way well). And, for some reason, such a construct always appears whenever I fiddle around with syntax design for never-materializing pet languages ..